# Dynamically getting filename

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm pretty new to jquery and coding in general. I'm trying to implement the jquery slideshow from http://www.designchemical.com/blog/index.php/jquery/jquery-image-swap-gallery/. I made it work through click instead of hover. I want the background of a div (with background repeat x and y) to change in the same manner as the thumbnail controls the main image.

It works fine with a given image:
$('#bgs').css('background-image','url(gallery/bgs/img_3.jpg)');
but I want it to work by dynamically getting the right filename in the same way that the main image does. I just don't know what to change.

The code is as follows:
http://pastebin.com/hvVYQyru

I hope I've made myself clear :). I really hope you Guys can get me on the right track.

Regards
Martin Schack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#bgs').css('background-image','url(' + $(this).attr('src').replace('thumb/', 'bgs/') + ')');
```

**UPDATE**

To achieve the same result using animation, it will require a bit more work. As it's not part of your original question, I'm leaving you a good link to check:

http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/jquery-bg-image-animations/

Comment: EXACTLY! Thanks so much! Next step is to hopefully integrate jquery easing to this effect. Do you think it's possible?

Comment: If I have understood this approach correctly, it won't be possible to make use of the easing lib... Am I right?

Comment: I've complemented the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your `bgs` image structure is the same as the main images and thumbnails, change this line:

```
$('#bgs').css('background-image','url(gallery/bgs/img_3.jpg)');
```

To:

```
$('#bgs').css('background-image', 'url(' + $(this).attr('src').replace('thumb/', 'bgs/') + ')');
```